# Invisible margin shown on Chrome

Tags: html, css

So I'm new to Web Design and coding in general. I'm trying to create a simple Social Network. i'm still at the design stage, and I'm currently having a really annoying issue. If you look at the screenshot that I have posted, I have selected a div called 'sideBar'. If I hover over it, I get an orange box on the right, which represents I have a margin. But if you look at my code I have made sure that the element, and all sub-elements, have no margin. Even chrome doesn't actually compute it, as it does not tell me its size. It just highlights it. How on earth do i remove this margin? I will link my code and a screenshot.

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}

#Introduction {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}

#sideBar {
 text-align: left;
}

h5 {
 color: rgb(209, 86, 33);
}

h3 {
 color: rgb(33, 171, 209);
}

.postContent{
 text-align: right;
 color: rgb(209, 174, 33);
}

#mainPage {
 text-align: right;
 width: 774px;
 float: right;
}

#sideBar *{
 width: 550px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}

#sideBar {
 width: 550px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>TimelineSocial</title>]
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='Introduction'>
   <h1>Welcome to Alabas Social!</h1>
   <h2>Here is your dashboard!</h2>
  </div>
  <div id='sideBar'>
   <div id='username'>
    <div id='signedInAs'>
     <h3>Username</h3>
     <h5>Saker Alabas</h5> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id='peopleYouMightKnow'>
    <div id='pplUmiteNo'>
     <h3>People You might know</h3>
     <h5>Dude Number 1</h5>
     <h5>Dude Number 2</h5>
     <h5>Dude Number 3</h5>
     <h5>Dude Number 4</h5>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id='yourFollowers'>
    <div id='urFllwers'>
     <h3>Your Followers</h3>
     <h5>Dude Number 1</h5>
     <h5>Dude Number 2</h5>
     <h5>Dude Number 3</h5>
     <h5>Dude Number 4</h5>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id='peopleYouFollow'>
    <div id='urFllwing'>
     <h3>People you follow</h3>
     <h5>Dude Number 1</h5>
     <h5>Dude Number 2</h5>
     <h5>Dude Number 3</h5>
     <h5>Dude Number 4</h5>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id='mainPage'>
   <div id='postFeed'>
    <h2>Posts</h2>
    <div class='post'>
     <div class='postContent'>
      <p>Wassup Fams</p>
     </div>
     <div class='postAuthor'>
      <h6>GuyDude</h6>
     </div>
     <div class='followAuthorPrompt'>
      <a><h6>Follow</h6></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here is a screenshot of the google chrome preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhcGa.png)

Comment: This is the default behavior of a block element that take all the horizontal space .. you set a fixed width so the remaining is the *margin* you see

Comment: you set  `sideBar` as div whats mean it takes 100% of width(`display:block`) the space you see as margin it because you set fixed width as `550px` my recoomand use :`display: inline-block;` or `flex` to wrap div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` elements are `display: block;` by default, that's why you see the "ghost" margin.

setting

```
#sideBar {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

should fix that.

you can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Thanks so much for this contribution! It really helps! Now I can carry on with he rest of my project.

Comment: @JefferyJohnson Hey... if this answer solved your issue... please mark as answer :https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow